# How to format longs in android to always display two digits

Tags: java, android, formatting

I have a countdown timer which shows seconds from 60 to 0 (1 min countdown timer). When it reaches 1 digit numbers such as 9,8,7.. it shows 9 instead of 09. I tried using `String.format("%[B]02d[/B]", x);`   where I converted x from long to string. It didn't work.

I want an equivalent of `String.format("%2d", 1)`

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can accomplish it with [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html):

```
NumberFormat f = new DecimalFormat("00");
long time = 9;
textView.setText(f.format(time));
```

**Output:**

```
09
```

Or you can use [String.format()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) as well:

```
String format = "%1$02d"; // two digits
textView.setText(String.format(format, time));
```

Comment: Is it possible instead of 09 display space9 (_9)?

Answer (score 11):

Use: `text.setText(String.format("%02d", i));` where `i` is the integer value

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use an if statement?

```
String str = x < 10 ? "0" + String.valueOf(x) : String.valueOf(x);
```

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

```
TextView time; 
int hour=0,minute=0,second=0;
time.setText((String.format("%02d", hour))+":"+(String.format("%02d", minute))+":"+(String.format("%02d", second)));
```

time to TextView

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
tv.setText(new DecimalFormat("##").format(var));
```

Comment: This won't work. `#` indicates an optional display, therefore single-digit will still display as a single digit, without 0.