# How to add an Extra zero in time for proper time format

Tags: android, calendar, timepicker, timepickerdialog

I am using a timepicker to choose the time and then show it in a toast in 24 hour format. I am getting output in toast like "2:6" And I want to get it in proper time format like "02:06". How can I do that....

```
public void ShowTimePicker(View view) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "timePicker");

}


public static class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
        implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current time as the default values for the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

        int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
                DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
    }

    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

        Toast myToast = Toast.makeText(getContext(), hourOfDay + ":" + minute, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        myToast.show();


    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format longs in android to always display two digits](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20293887/how-to-format-longs-in-android-to-always-display-two-digits)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First need to create one function that check your input and convert it in String as per condition.

```
public String convertDate(int input) {
  if (input >= 10) {
    return String.valueOf(input);
  } else {
    return "0" + String.valueOf(input);
  }
}
```

Then you can call like this

```
txtTime.setText(convertDate(hourOfDay) + ":" + convertDate(minute));
```

And your Toast will be like this

```
Toast myToast = Toast.makeText(getContext(), convertDate(hourOfDay) + ":" + convertDate(minute), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
```

Comment: This is not a rational solution. Its patch

Answer (score 10):

`int` is just an integer. Integers don't have leading zeros. They can only be displayed with leading zeros when you convert them to `String` objects. One way to do that is like this:

```
int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

String curTime = String.format("%02d:%02d", hour, minute);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
private String fillText(int i){
    return i>9?i+"":"0"+i;
}
```

...

```
 Toast myToast = Toast.makeText(getContext(), fillText(hourOfDay) + ":" + filllText(minute), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use SimpleDateFormat for date and time formatting:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy"); 
String string = sdf.format(callendar);
```

Information about time patterns you can find here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 1):

You can Write this

```
  Toast myToast = Toast.makeText(getContext(), hourOfDay <10? "0"+hourOfDay :hourOfDay  + ":" + minute<10:"0"+minute:minute, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use the String.format as follow :

```
String format = "%1$02d"; // two digits
Toast.makeText(getContext(), String.format(format, hourOfDay)+ ":" + String.format(format, minute, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this string ressource in your strings.xml

```
<string name="time_remaining">%1$02d:%2$02d</string>
```

In your onTimeSet function you can use it as follow:

```
String time = getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.time_remaining, hourOfDay, minute);
Toast myToast = Toast.makeText(getContext(), time, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
myToast.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

### Kotlin v.1.4.x

This is an extension of Int:

```
fun Int.to2DString():String{
    return String.format("%02d",this)
}
```

### Usage:

```
val formattedMinute = timePicker.minute.to2DString()
```